# Gnome Shell - Battery only charges to about 90-91%

Tags: gnome, battery

In Gnome Shell, I am charging my battery but it won't go past 91% at the most.  It sometimes gets stuck at 90 as well.  Its very annoying and I want to know if there is a fix for this...

Comment: Can you charge the batter to full using another desktop session (e.g. Unity/Unity2D)?

Comment: It always charged to full on Unity.

Comment: UPDATE - After going back to Unity, that too says its stuck below 100%.  And everytime I turn off and on my computer, the percentage keeps getting less and less.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the desktop session you are using. There is something wrong with your battery, so I would recommend buying a new battery.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with your battery. Your battery has either stopped functioning properly or has reached the end of its life. You should buy a new battery.